# Removing range (tail) from a List

Tags: java, list, collections, stack

Is there an efficient method to remove a range - say the tail - of X elements from a `List`, e.g. `LinkedList` in Java?

It is obviously possible to remove the last elements one by one, which should result in O(X) level performance. At least for `LinkedList` instances it should be possible to have O(1) performance (by setting the references around the first element to be removed and setting the head/tail references). Unfortunately I don't see any method within `List` or `LinkedList` to remove the last elements all at once.

Currently I am thinking of *replacing* the list by using [`List.subList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) but I'm not sure if that has equal performance. At least it would be more clear within the code, on the other hand I would loose the additional functionality that `LinkedList` provides.

I'm mainly using the List as a stack, for which `LinkedList` seems to be the best option, at least regarding semantics.

Comment: Have you read the caveats of subList() - namely that it's just a view and all bets are off if the backing list is structurally modified?

Comment: Your O(1) performance ignores the O(N) cost of looking up the N-th last element.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`subList(list.size() - N, list.size()).clear()` is the recommended way to remove the last `N` elements.  Indeed, the [Javadoc for `subList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) *specifically* recommends this idiom:

> This method eliminates the need for explicit range operations (of the sort that commonly exist for arrays). Any operation that expects a list can be used as a range operation by passing a subList view instead of a whole list. For example, the following idiom removes a range of elements from a list:
>
> ```
>  list.subList(from, to).clear();
> ```

Indeed, I suspect that this idiom might be *more* efficient (albeit by a constant factor) than calling `removeLast()` `N` times, just because once it finds the `N`th-to-last node, it only needs to update a constant number of pointers in the linked list, rather than updating the pointers of each of the last `N` nodes one at a time.

Comment: For an `ArrayList`, according to my test, speed is about the same as for the obvious `while (list.size() > max) list.remove(list.size() - 1);`

Comment: @ThomasMueller That's good info! I'd still use the method above of course as it may be faster for some situations / implementations. In my opinion it is at least as clear as removing each element individually. It has been designed for this use case it seems, so using is unlikely to fail - let's use it!

Answer (score 15):

Be aware that `subList()` returns a *view* of the original list, meaning:

1. Any modification done to the view will be reflected in the original list
2. The returned list is *not* a `LinkedList` - it's an inner implementation of `List` that's not serializable

Anyway, using either `removeFirst()` or `removeLast()` should be efficient enough, because popping the first or last element of a linked list in Java is an `O(1)` operation - internally, `LinkedList` holds pointers to both ends of the list and removing either one is as simple as moving a pointer one position.

For removing `m` elements at once, you're stuck with `O(m)` performance with a `LinkedList`, although strangely enough an `ArrayList` might be a better option, because removing elements at the end of an `ArrayList` is as simple as moving an index pointer (denoting the end of the array) one position to its left, and no garbage nodes are left dangling as is the case with a `LinkedList`. The best choice? try both approaches, profile them and let the numbers speak for themselves.